# Wavefunction properties tunnel effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

$$ \psi_E(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{ikx}+Ae^{-ikx}  \quad \quad  x \le0 \\   
Ce^{ikx} \quad \quad x\ge a \\ 
\end{cases} $$
where $k^2=\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$.

Now what I read in my notes is

> "since the eigenfunctions of SE equation must not be equal to zero in a point with their first derivatives, then $C \neq 0$".

How can I prove this statement? Is due to the fact that the SE is $\psi''(x)=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi(x)$ so that the eigenfunction must have concavity facing upward when it's negative and concavity facing downward when it's positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenfunction of the 1D Schrödinger equation satisfy a second order linear differential equation. If there is a point $x$ where $\psi(x) = \psi'(x) = 0$, then $\psi$ is zero everywhere, which is not allowed.

Comment: I can't understand. Why would be zero everywhere? I just have a Cauchy's problem that "select" one of the solutions of the TISE.

Comment: The constant zero function is a solution of the TISE and has the same Cauchy data

Comment: Ok thank you. Are we assuming that there is a unique solution for Cauchy problem? Otherwise, why the fact that the constant zero is a solution of the TISE with same Cauchy data would be a problem? I mean: couldn't there be other functions that solve the TISE and Cauchy problem other than zero?

Comment: In your particular case, the solutions are of the form $\psi(x) = A e^{ikx}  + Be^{-ikx}$. It is not hard to see that the Cauchy problem has a unique solution. In general, you may need to assume some regularity for the potential $V(x)$.